# Trouble reading an integer with fscanf

Tags: c, file, fopen

I've been struggling for more than a day trying to figure out what's wrong with this piece of code,printf is always printing 0 on my screen.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
int one=0,two=0;
FILE *arq;
arq = fopen ("testando.txt","w+");
fprintf(arq,"1,2,3\n");
fscanf(arq,"%d%d",&one,&two);
printf("%d %d\n",one,two);

return 0;
```

}

Comment: [Be kind, rewind](https://www.google.com/search?q=Be+kind,+rewind&client=opera&hs=poK&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiL6fnv-c7cAhWSxVkKHblaDIYQ_AUICigB&biw=1504&bih=774#imgrc=NBTNdpbTXzYxhM:) Try adding `rewind(arg);` before the `fscanf()`.  Check results of `fopen, fscanf()` and `','` per the below answer.

Comment: When posting code, paste it in, select it, and click the `{}` widget.  That will shift it right 4 spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code (which you can see in the preview before you submit.)

Comment: Thanks for the tips guys. I'll try to use rewind(arq) always when switching between reading and printing.

Comment: The best way to say "thanks" is to up-vote useful comments, up-vote helpful answers, and most importantly, select the best answer (click the check-mark).  And Welcome to StackOverflow!  You got off to a good start by posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: An important thing to learn, which is implicit in @whý's answer, is that _you cannot read the data you just wrote to the file without first taking some action_. Such as closing the file and then reopening it for reading, or seeking on an `rw` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add commas in `fscanf(arq,"%d%d",&one,&two);`
2. Reopen file with `r` flag - to read it
3. Don't forget to close files ;)
4. Opt. you can use return value of fscanf to check how much properties are filled

This works fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    int one=0,two=0;
    FILE *arq;
    arq = fopen ("testando.txt","w+");
    fprintf(arq,"1,2,3\n");
    fclose(arq);

    arq = fopen("testando.txt","r");
    int r = fscanf(arq,"%d,%d",&one,&two);
    fclose(arq);
    printf("%d %d %d\n",r, one,two);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2 1 2
```

Comment: 1. Are commas necessary? Or are they optional?
4. I didn't quite understand the int r part,could you explain it better please?
And thanks a lot for the help!
+1

Comment: Generally not, depends on what you want to scan. He is saving value returned from fscanf (how many arguments were scanned sucessfully). You may then perform check if all values were scanned correctly: `if (r != 2) error`. You may get further explanation by searching on google, its common question.

Comment: Commas are necessary (atleast using [this compiler](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler) )
To understand return value of `fscanf` you can check [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)

Comment: Got it,guys!
Thanks so much for all the help,tutoring in my university ended and I needed this help so bad...
+9999

Comment: A close and re-open is not truly needed.

Comment: @chux: Right: close and repoen is not needed, if  you open it originally using "rw" or "rw+".  For this program, though, you'd want to use "rw" and *not* "rw+".  Using the latter, you'd get odd results if you changed the code and ran it again in the same directory (you'd get the results from the earlier run.)

Comment: While it's a good idea to get in the habit of always closing a file you've opened, `exit()` (or just returning from `main`) is guaranteed to close all open files.